# gradle dependency unusable after refresh in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, twitter4j

as in the title, gradle dependency unusable after refreshing. I can see twitter4j is added in external libraries along with other gradle dependencies.

Gradle file:

```
compile group: 'org.twitter4j', name: 'twitter4j', version: '4.0.6', ext: 'pom'
```

java:

```
import twitter4j.*;
```

error:

```
cannot resolve symbol "twitter4j"
```

Answer (score 0):

changing the gradle line to

```
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.6'
```

resolves this problem.